# what is the name of this effect?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, final-cut-pro-x

[image: image from a music video]

Hello do you know the name of this effect please?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an aged film effect.  There are a great many different aged film effects available.

Comment: thank you for your answer the effect is applied in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPuKknqnVfg   at 2:28